# Creating a Simple React CDN Boilerplate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

REACT HELP: Trying to build a very basic React boilerplate because doing Create-React-App seems like overkill for some basic practice. In this repo there is two boilerplate files, the second works but then all the code would be in one file. The second file point to start.js as the app component but when I run it in the browser nothing appears. What am I overlooking, I’ve seen several other boilerplates and doesn’t seem like I’m doing anything different.

https://git.generalassemb.ly/AlexMerced/PracticeRepo/tree/master/react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to `import React from "react"` which doesn't exist. In a standalone version I think you will get a global React and ReactDOM objects. You can use them to render the component. Remove the import statements from start.js  Edited code below.

```js
class Greeting extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <p>Hello world</p>;
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Greeting />, document.getElementById("start"));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>React Boilerplate</title>



  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="start"></div>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.6.2/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="./start.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I appreciate the advice, but this not seem to work either, someone else suggest to add an export statement at the end of start.js which did not work either.

Comment: I have loaded the same code to a public URL. https://agitated-wiles-8a4b8b.netlify.com/ Can you please take a look and let me know what didn't work here. If this doesn't help, let me know. You can do a browser inspect and verify its the same code that I posted as answer

Comment: yeah, not working on my laptop but I'm trying to run with nothing in the folder but the index.html and start.js, I'll more the files to another device and see if I get different results. I guess I'll just continue to CRA app, it just loads so many files into the folder for basic practice.

Comment: Ok, been awhile since this question, aside from the import statements the other issue I had in hindsight was I was trying to run react without running a server like lite-server so Babel couldn’t translate the JSX. So the setup is right just didn’t know I had to run a server not just open the file in the browser, now I’m a lot wiser :). Hope this helps future baby devs who were confused like I was.